# Asp.net ajax query returning page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying at first to run ajax request using jQuery in my page. On view page
`localhost:1382/Home/Index` I have this code:

```
...bla-bla, another usless code..
 $.ajax({
                        url: "Index/ShowStadium",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "text",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: "",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $(".right-content").html(data);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                            $(".right-content").html("в этом клубе нет спортивных площадок");
                        }

                    });
...other usless code...
```

So I put a function named `ShowStadium()` in my `HomeController`. But every time I got one of this errors:

1. 200 - Parse error.
2. Ok ,  but response is a full page.

Here is my `HomeController` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjectMVC.Models;
using System.Web.Services;

    namespace ProjectMVC.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private readonly Initializer init = new Initializer();

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(EventDetails obj)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                   ViewData["Error"] = "nice one!";
                   return Redirect("/home/index2.cshtml");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = "Заполните необходимые поля, пожалуйста";  // If JS disabled
                }
                return View();
            }

            [WebMethod]
            public static string ShowStadium()
            {
                return "Футбольное поле";
            }
        }
    }
```

As I told, the biggest problem for me is a page in response, the page of view which returning `HomeController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need webMethod for this use action instead:

```
public ActionResult ShowStadium()
{
    return Content("Футбольное поле");
}
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "HOme/ShowStadium",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "text",
      type: "POST",                       
      success: function (data) {
          $(".right-content").html(data);
      },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
          alert(textStatus);
          $(".right-content").html("в этом клубе нет спортивных площадок");
     }
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain me why in all tuttorial videos adding [webMethod] before response function ?

Comment: @dantey89 because those tutorials are probably for asp.net webforms and this is asp.net mvc.